# Laravel: Finding row by xp_start and xp_end

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to find a certain row in a MySQL table just by having a number. I have a number with is the `xp_current` in my users table, I need to find the row in another table between two columns.

This is for a leveling system. Each level has a column called `xp_start` and `xp_end`, now the first level's `xp_start` is `0` obviously, how do I find the record just by the `current_xp` ?

I am using Laravel framework. I've looked all over google but I can't find anything related to MySQL PHP alone, never mind Laravel. I also don't know where to start so I haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide you the mysql query to do that so you can convert it to whatever you want

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE current_exp > xp_start AND current_exp < xp_end
```

So you'll find the row corresponding to the actual level.

Comment: This seems so basic but I really couldn't think, thank you. I thing this is better though: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE xp_start <= current_exp AND xp_end >= current_exp`

Comment: Yes of course, it may suits your needs better. Could you upvote if I have been helpful please? :)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you can do like this:

```
$level = DB::table('levels')->where('xp_start','<=',$current_xp)->where('xp_end','>=',$current_xp)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$level = DB::table('levels')
    ->where('xp_start', '<=', $currentXp)
    ->where('xp_end', '>=', $currentXp)
    ->get();
```